# Angular2 : How to forbid one of the radio elements?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, radio-button

I'm trying to have a form with a list of select on radio and one of the radio is disabled.

Code:

```
  <fieldset class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
<legend class="col-form-legend sr-only">Type data</legend>
<div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' name='type-data' id='type-data1' value='one' disabled="false" />
      Data 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' name='type-data' id='type-data2' value='one' disabled="true" />
      Data 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' name='type-data' id='type-data3' value='one' disabled="false" />
      Data 3
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, I have all elements disabled.

Why?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you include the `disabled` attribute, no matter what you set it to, it will disable the control.

Delete all your `disabled="false"`

In the future if you want to disable an attribute, just add `disabled`.

```
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

If you wish to data-bind the disabled state to an Angular component:

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="booleanComponentVar"/>
```

Angular will remove `disabled` attribute for you when `booleanComponentVar` is false.

Comment: And also the value of attribute 'name' must be same the value of attribute 'id' ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `disabled` from the elements which you don't want to disable. 
For the reference on using disabled, [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)

In your case, remove `disabled="false"` from element 1 and 3.

Since you are using angular, you could also make use of `ng-disabled` attribute

Comment: *you could also make use of ng-disabled*. No, this won't work in Angular ;)

Comment: Yes, or rather we are talking about "AngularJS" for version 1.x.x and "Angular" for version 2.x.x. Important to remember for example for tagging questions. This has tagged "angular" so it means it's version 2 and up :) But not to worry, these get often mixed up :D